# Storing dynamic form field as an array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

question.component.ts

```
   ngOnInit() {
        this.challengeId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('challengeId');
        // this.selectedNoOfAttempt = this.noofattempts[1];
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
          question: ['', [Validators.required]],
          correctAnswers: this._fb.array([
            this.initCorrectAnswer(),
        ]),
          selectedNoOfAttempt: ['', [Validators.required]]
      });
      }

      initCorrectAnswer() {
        return this._fb.group({
          correctAnswers: ['', Validators.required],
        });
      }

      addAnswer() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['correctAnswers'];
        control.push(this.initCorrectAnswer());
      }

      removeAnswer(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['correctAnswers'];
        control.removeAt(i);
      }
```

question.component.html

```
 <div formArrayName="correctAnswers">
    <div *ngFor="let correctAnswers of myForm.controls.correctAnswers.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span>Answer {{i + 1}}</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="myForm.controls.correctAnswers.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAnswer(i)">Remove</span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="correctAnswers">
          <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.correctAnswers.controls[i].controls.correctAnswers.valid" class="text-danger">
            Answer is required
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="margin-20">
    <a (click)="addAnswer()" style="cursor: default">
      Add another answer +
    </a>
  </div>
```

The code above works as it is intended, dynamically insert more fields if needed, and also remove. It also able to return all the dynamic fields, however it is storing the data as

```
 correctAnswers (array)
           [0]  (object)
             correctAnswers: "test" (string)
           [1]  (object)
             correctAnswers: "abc"  (string)
```

I would like to store the data as follow

```
 correctAnswers (array)
           [0] "test" (string)
           [1] "abc"  (string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `initCorrectAnswer()` function you are adding form group with child form control to your form array, that is why you see it as array of objects. Instead of this, you should add form control:

```
initCorrectAnswer() {
  return this._fb.control('', Validators.required);
}
```

I also added `correctAnswers` *getter* for convenient use in HTML:

```
get correctAnswers(): FormArray { 
  return this.myForm.get('correctAnswers') as FormArray; 
}
```

updated `add` and `remove` functions:

```
addAnswer() {
 this.correctAnswers.push(this.initCorrectAnswer());
}

removeAnswer(i: number) {
  this.correctAnswers.removeAt(i);
}
```

here is HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="correctAnswers">
    <div class="panel panel-default" 
         *ngFor="let correctAnswer of correctAnswers.controls; index as i">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span>Answer {{i + 1}}</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"
              *ngIf="correctAnswers.controls.length > 1" 
              (click)="removeAnswer(i)">Remove</span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
          <small [hidden]="correctAnswer.valid" class="text-danger">
            Answer is required
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-643srq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

[Official reference](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName#example)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to achieve it through Angular's reactive form, because every form group that is repeated (via your `*ngFor`) is an object. Note that your form group name is actually your `*ngFor` index: `formGroupName = i`; and that your form control is `correctAnswers` - that corresponds to your object property with name `correctAnswers` as you have expected it.

You can however, do some post processing though. Simply use an array `map()` to flatten your object into arrays:

```
var flattenedArray = this.myForm.correctAnswers.map(x=>x.correctAnswers);
```